# How do I have a full signal of noise on a handheld?

Tags: antenna, ht, baofeng, noise

I'm new to ham (although I've had a license for a long time) and I'm having issues with receiving on a basic handheld. I have a cheap BaoFeng UV-82HP and I keep getting full signal noise at random times. I have gotten this on different channels in different locations. When I'm not getting the noise, I get clean and clear transmissions.

**Video Evidence:**
https://youtu.be/nupqlH3-eQ0

**Power/Ground Troubleshooting:**
The unit is a battery operated handheld, so I don't have to worry about power input.

**Antenna Troubleshooting:**
I have tried three different antennas including a rubber duck and they all have the same issue. I assume the rubber duck doesn't need grounding as it is very small and not really ground-able.

I assume that means that means the noise is a defect in the radio?

Comment: Hey Eric, welcome to the site and hopefully you'll be more active in the hobby.  Not to be pedantic, but radio amateurs typically don't call the hobby "ham", as in "I'm new to ham".  Instead say, "I'm new to ham radio".

Comment: Haha @mike65535 I happy accept the critique.

Comment: Power lines: if you are very close to them you will rx noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not noise, it's digital voice. DMR, DSTAR, and P25 are digital modes that find popular use on the amateur bands.

Some repeaters are digital-only. Others are dual-mode, so you will encounter a mix of digital and analog FM, depending on what the other station is transmitting. If you can find information on the repeater, you will probably discover what modes it supports.

On a cursory look, it does not appear the UV-82HP supports any digital modes, so unfortunately you won't be able to participate without a different radio or some software.

Related: [How to scan while avoiding digital/noise frequencies?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/11853/how-to-scan-while-avoiding-digital-noise-frequencies)

Comment: +1  ... I thought is was a TV or something else nearby.  ;-)

Comment: Oh that would make a lot of sense. Is there any way for me to mute those transmissions? Is there a radio (HT and/or mobile) as cheap as the Baofeng that supports these?

Comment: None are as cheap as the Baofengs, but the Tytera UV-380 is fairly reasonably priced and quite good as a monoband analog radio, too.  I wrote a review of it in QST Magazine last year, if you want to learn more.  I'm quite happy with mine.

Comment: You mention software; does that mean there's an SDR solution to this, Phil?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Kinda, though it's encumbered by the proprietary AMBE codec. A couple things to check out: https://brandmeister.network/ http://www.dvdongle.com/DV_Dongle/Home.html https://github.com/g4klx/MMDVM